# PriorityBinding - Use different StringFormat for each binding in a Label

Tags: wpf, xaml

In my WPF project, I have a `Label`:

```
<Label Grid.Column="1"
       Grid.Row="1">
    <PriorityBinding>
        <Binding Path="Worker.Employer.Name" StringFormat="Employer: {0}" />
        <Binding Source="Unemployed" />
    </PriorityBinding>
</Label>
```

The StringFormat on doesn't seem to do anything. However, if I add this:

```
<Label.ContentStringFormat>
    Employer: {0}
</Label.ContentStringFormat>
```

... the formatting works, but it affects both bindings. How can I apply the StringFormat to only the top binding?

**Update:** So short of using a `TextBlock` instead of a `Label`, is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already explained StringFormat only works when the target property type is text.

One solution would be to use a ValueConverter to format the result, you can pass in the format string as the ConverterParameter.

Failing that create an attached DependencyProperty of type string

```
public static class Helper {
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Text", typeof(string), typeof(Helper));

   public static string GetText(DependencyObject o) {
     return (string)o.GetValue(TextProperty);
   }

   public static void SetText(DependencyObject o, string value) {
      o.SetValue(TextProperty,value);
   }
}
```

Then you can do

```
<Label Grid.Column="1"
       Grid.Row="1" 
       Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(ui:Helper.Text)}">
    <ui:Helper.Text>
    <PriorityBinding>
        <Binding Path="Worker.Employer.Name" StringFormat="Employer: {0}" />
        <Binding Source="Unemployed" />
    </PriorityBinding>
    </ui:Helper.Text>
</Label>
```

The problem describe in the comments may be related to [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5746177/weird-wpf-error-with-attached-propery) and so the XAML might need to look like this.

```
<Label Grid.Column="1"
       Grid.Row="1" >
       <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"  Path="(ui:Helper.Text)" />
      <ui:Helper.Text>
      <PriorityBinding>
          <Binding Path="Worker.Employer.Name" StringFormat="Employer: {0}" />
          <Binding Source="Unemployed" />
      </PriorityBinding>
      </ui:Helper.Text>
</Label>
```

Or from [this MSDN question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/dbee944d-28b5-485f-9410-e6668bd573c7/xaml-bug-when-using-attached-properties) you could do

```
<Label Grid.Column="1"
       Grid.Row="1" >
      <ui:Helper.Text>
      <PriorityBinding>
          <Binding Path="Worker.Employer.Name" StringFormat="Employer: {0}" />
          <Binding Source="Unemployed" />
      </PriorityBinding>
      </ui:Helper.Text>
      <Label.Content>
         <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"  Path="(ui:Helper.Text)" />
      </Label.Content>
    </Label>
```

Make sure that you bind the xmlns for ui to the namespace of your Helper class

You could always put the Content relative source binding into a style to avoid repeating it for all labels.

Comment: I'm getting the following errors with your solution:
`The object 'Label' already has a child and cannot add ''. 'Label' can accept only one child.` and `The name "Helper" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:AoW.Helpers".` The class is there and referenced properly. Intellisense even picks it up in the XAML. I've cleaned and rebuilt the solution.

Comment: Restarted VS and the namespace issue went away, but I still get this error `The object 'Label' already has a child and cannot add ''. 'Label' can accept only one child.`

Comment: I believe that its trying to add the empty space a content, I've updated the answer, but you may also need to remove the spaces and new lines between the label opening/closing tags and the `ui:Helper.Text`  opening/closing tags

Comment: Updated answer with workarounds for the issue, this seems to be a common problem with content controls and attached properties

Comment: All 3 of those examples work perfectly. I went ahead and accepted your answer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Also, the 2 lines containing `<Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"  Path="(ui:Helper.Text)">` need closing tags. I tried to edit it myself but the minimum edit is 6 characters.

Answer (score 3):

StringFormat is for string (eg TextBlock.Text), but label.Content is type of object and there for you have to use ContentStringFormat for Label.

edit: to your question - if you can chang label to TextBlock then you have no problems anymore. but if you wanna stay with label i would guess you have to use a converter to apply your string format.