# The object 'Label' already has a child and cannot add ''. 'Label' can accept only one child

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am trying to use a helper class that another SO user provided me to apply stringformatting on a label. However, when I apply his solution, I get the following error :

`The object 'Label' already has a child and cannot add ''. 'Label' can accept only one child.`

Here is the label:

```
<Label Grid.Column="1"
       Grid.Row="1">
    <ui:Helper.Text>
        <PriorityBinding>
            <Binding Path="Worker.Employer.Name" StringFormat="Employer: {0}" />
            <Binding Source="Unemployed" />
        </PriorityBinding>
    </ui:Helper.Text>
    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="(ui:Helper.Text)" />
</Label>
```

The error points at the "Binding RelativeSource..." line. What can I do to fix this? I would like to use `Label`s instead of `TextBlock`s, but it's getting to the point where it might not be worth it.

Comment: Then where should it go? If I put it with the other bindings, the label displays nothing. I'm a beginner here and was going off of an answer I got to another question.

Comment: This one here, to be specific: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17178739/1667020

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just looks like a case of xaml assuming your attached property to be the `Content` of the `Label`

just wrap your actual `Content` in an explicit `<Label.Content>`

```
<Label Grid.Row="1"
       Grid.Column="1">
  <ui:Helper.Text>
    <PriorityBinding>
      <Binding Path="Worker.Employer.Name"
               StringFormat="Employer: {0}" />
      <Binding Source="Unemployed" />
    </PriorityBinding>
  </ui:Helper.Text>
  <Label.Content>
    <Binding Path="(ui:Helper.Text)"
             RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" />
  </Label.Content>
</Label>
```

Comment: Then how do Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf work like this?
```<behaviors:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <behaviors:MouseDragElementBehavior ConstrainToParentBounds="True" />
</behaviors:Interaction.Behaviors>```
They coexist with the implicit Content property without any problems.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/XamlBehaviorsWpf/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors/Interaction.cs Here's the source code, but doing the same won't work. Trying to figure out this magic

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/XamlBehaviorsWpf/issues/100

Answer (score 1):

Without having tested i, I suppose there's a bug in the definition of the attached property, because it is attached to the `Helper` class itself and not to `Label`. That way you just create a new instance of `Helper` in your labels content. When you then add the binding to the content as well, you get the exception, because there already is a content.

I don't actually see a reason to make it an attached property anyway and binding to the attached property of self seems clumsy to me.

Try the following; Make Helper.Text a normal dependency property by replacing `RegisterAttached(...)` with `Register(...)`. (Rename helper to something like `CompositeString`.) Then define a CompositeString as a resource of the label and bind the content of the label to this resource:

```
<Label>
    <Label.Resources>
        <ui:CompositeString>
            <ui:CompositeString.Text>...</ui:CompositeString.Text>
        </ui:CompositeString>
    </Label.Resources>
    <Label.Content>
        <Binding Path="Text" Source="{StaticResource Test}" />
     </Label.Content>
</Label>
```

Note, that the resource needs to be defined before binding to the content, that's why the binding gets its own tag.